# PHP cannot print my string properly

Tags: php, string, printing, echo

so I have the following code:

```
$tag = 'script';
$r = '#(<'.$tag.'.*?>).*?(</'.$tag.'>)#';
echo $r;
```

but then when it echoes, it merely echoes this: `#().*?()#`

not even the 'script' is being echoed.....and notice that the less than equal sign, etc are not there...

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not so sure. http://codepad.org/vCUmQoA2

Comment: check out this one: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Then I suggest your look at @Itay Moav's answer...

Comment: Although this is noob question, I do not see why it is a bad question. If it does not fit the site, vote to close it (who ever dowvoted).

Comment: @rockerest Most people in the world are jerks and idiots, why would you expect it different in any other community. I myself am a Jerk many many times. It is easier.

Comment: Not to get off topic here, but probably because of drive-by "reviews" and the consensus that the original question is flawed or possibly wrong. I didn't downvote (I rarely do that anymore), but I can see how the cursory view would see it as not "worthwhile" due the responses. And then others pile on...

Comment: @Itay Moav, it just seems stupid to come to a site dedicated to helping others, and then downvote a question that has nothing inherently wrong with it, but that you deem "bad."  Just because it's obvious to one person doesn't mean it's obvious to someone else.  I've been noticing a lot more frequently that the people on Stack Overflow have a huge ego problem.  There's a very elitist aura here that's really turning me off, not to mention people who disregard actually HELPING the OP for just spouting the specific wording of rules or standards.  SO is for helping, just leave if you can't help.

Comment: @rockerest - We're all here to "help", some more compassionately than others. If you're accusing IT/programmers of being elitist or of having ego issues, you're probably not living in the world I do (since yeah, these folks do have those problems, I digress), or you're denying the kind of effort it takes to master IT-related issues (usually involving denying yourself sunshine and external friends). I try to help. If you do too, we can all do some good. :) But don't be discouraged. We hear you.

Comment: @rockerest It seems you have some misunderstanding, I was on your side...and I actually helped :-) (see below).

Comment: @Itay Moav my "you" was a general you, and not directed at you, specifically (as in Itay Moav).  I could have just as easily made the comment without addressing you (Itay) but you addressed me, so I chose to address back :)  I wasn't blaming you or even suggesting that you exhibit the traits that I've noticed frequently on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do **view source** to see why.
It will probbably be:

```
#(<script.*?>).*?(</script>)#';
```

Which each browser will display as

> #().*?()#

As it hides any XML tags from the parsed view, i.e hides the `<script.*?>` and the `</script>`
which can be seen, though, in the unparsed version->**view source**

Comment: Or in Firebug, right-click on the suspicious text, select `Inspect Element` and see the script tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you're printing to HTML or a web browser, it will be ignoring tags it doesn't understand or wouldn't normally display, like `<script>`.  See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmXKQ/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it print

```
#(<script.*?>).*?(</script>)
```

It's invisible to the browser but look in the source code, it should be there :D